# Resolve schedule conflicts using python

Tags: python

so I have the input of n users schedules, I want to form a new schedule that shows times **Union**

this is the input

> ['08:00-08:50', '09:00-09:50', '10:00-10:50', '11:00-11:50',
>   '11:00-12:15', '12:00-12:50', '12:00-13:15', '13:00-13:50',
>   '14:00-15:15', '15:30-18:10']

The output should be like this

> ['08:00-08:50', '09:00-09:50', '10:00-10:50', '11:00-13:50',
>   '14:00-15:15', '15:30-18:10']

That what i have tried so far

```
if start_currenttime < start_oldtime and end_currenttime >= start_oldtime:
    start=start_currenttime
    flag=1

    if end_currenttime>end_oldtime:
        end=end_currenttime

if start_currenttime >= start_oldtime and start_currenttime <= end_oldtime and end_currenttime > end_oldtime:
    flag=1
    end=end_currenttime

if flag:
     return str(start)+"-"+str(end)
else: return "-1"
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please show us what you tried. SO is not a code-writing service, we can help you with debugging. | Hint: it's easy if the time is sorted, like in your example input.

Comment: I did sort the input, so it is exactly same as what i've written above :)

Comment: Something like https://pypi.org/project/intervaltree/ would come in handy here…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way how you can do it, with basic for loop:

```
data = ['08:00-08:50', '09:00-09:50', '10:00-10:50', '11:00-11:50', '11:00-12:15', '12:00-12:50', '12:00-13:15', '13:00-13:50', '14:00-15:15', '15:30-18:10']
data_ = [interval.split('-') for interval in data]


interval_idx = 0
for i in data_:
    if i[0] > data_[interval_idx][1]:
        interval_idx += 1
        data_[interval_idx] = i
    else:
        data_[interval_idx] = [data_[interval_idx][0], i[1]]

data_=['-'.join(interval) for interval in data_[:interval_idx+1]]

print(data_)
```

output:

```
['08:00-08:50', '09:00-09:50', '10:00-10:50', '11:00-13:50', '14:00-15:15', '15:30-18:10']
```

Answer (score 2):

As @h4z3 has hinted, it is important to start with a sorted list, where the start of each interval is in ascending order. Given that times within a day are lexicographically sorted, we do not need to parse the actual times, handling them as strings is enough

```
data = ['08:00-08:50', '09:00-09:50', '10:00-10:50', '12:00-12:50', '11:00-11:50', '11:00-12:15', '12:00-13:15', '13:00-13:50', '14:00-15:15', '15:30-18:10']

def parse_intervals(data):
    return [tuple(interval.split('-')) for interval in data]

intervals = sorted(parse_intervals(data))

results = []
start_oldtime, stop_oldtime = intervals[0]
for start_currenttime, stop_currenttime in intervals:
    # if the start of the new is later than the end of the new, close the old
    if stop_oldtime < start_currenttime :
        results.append('-'.join([start_oldtime, stop_oldtime]))
        start_oldtime = start_currenttime
        stop_oldtime = stop_currenttime
    # if the end is later, extend the interval
    else:
        stop_oldtime = max(stop_currenttime, stop_oldtime)

# add any started interval
results.append('-'.join([start_oldtime, stop_oldtime]))

print(results)
```

You start with a temporary interval that is equal to the first interval. The next command will have a start that is equal or later than the old start, so no problem there.

- If the start is later than the old stop, the intervals are disjoint, so you can close the old interval and take the new one as reference
- If the start is equal or earlier than the old stop, the intervals overlap, so just take the latest end

At the end there is always on pending interval that has to be added.

## Output:

```
['08:00-08:50', '09:00-09:50', '10:00-10:50', '11:00-13:50', '14:00-15:15', '15:30-18:10']
```

Answer (score 2):

My go at it, assuming a sorted list:

```
schedules = ['08:00-08:50', '09:00-09:50', '10:00-10:50', '11:00-11:50', '11:00-12:15', '12:00-12:50', '12:00-13:15', '13:00-13:50', '14:00-15:15', '15:30-18:10']

def merge_overlap(ranges):
    intervals = [a_range.split('-') for a_range in ranges]

    merged_intervals = []
    current_interval = intervals[0]
    for interval in intervals:
        if current_interval[1] < interval[0]:
            merged_intervals.append(current_interval)
            current_interval = interval
        else:
            current_interval[1] = interval[1]
    merged_intervals.append(current_interval)
    return merged_intervals


print(merge_overlap(schedules))
```

1. Split by '-'
2. Have an empty `merged_intervals` to be populated, and a `current_interval` to merge an overlapping interval before adding it to `merged_intervals`
3. Traverse over `intervals`
4. If the upper bound of the `current_interval` is lower than the lower bound of the `interval` add it to `merged_intervals` and set the `current_interval` to `interval`
5. If not, merge into `current_interval`, by: `(current_interval[1] = interval[1])`

Answer (score 1):

My idea here can be broken down into three conditions. First, we will loop over two timings at a time, let us call the frist one `timing` and the second one `next_timing`. We will then check each of these timings upto the following conditions. Of course, I am assuming that the array is SORTED.

- If `next_timing` is completely included in `timing`, we will delete it.
- If `next_timing` intersects with `timing`, we will update `timing` to have the ending of `next_timing` and delete `next_timing`.
- If `next_timing` is completely disjoint from `timing`, we will just do nothing.

I implemented the previous algorithm as follows:

```
timings = ['08:00-08:50', '09:00-09:50', '10:00-10:50',
        '11:00-11:50', '11:00-12:15', '12:00-12:50',
        '12:00-13:15', '13:00-13:50', '14:00-15:15',
        '15:30-18:10']
# split to easily find start and end timing
timings = [t.split('-') for t in timings]

def is_within_the_range(timing,next_timing):
    return True if timing[0] >= next_timing[0] and timing[1]>=next_timing[1] else False

def is_intersecting(timing,next_timing):
    return True if timing[0] <=  next_timing[0] and timing[1] > next_timing[0] and timing[1] < next_timing[1] else False

i = 1
while i < len(timings):
timing = timings[i-1]
next_timing = timings[i]
if is_within_the_range(timing,next_timing):
    del timings[i]
    i = i-1
elif is_intersecting(timing,next_timing):
    timing[1] = next_timing[1]
    timings[i-1] = timing
    del timings[i]
    i = i-1
i+=1 

print(timings)
```

output:

```
[['08:00', '08:50'], ['09:00', '09:50'], ['10:00', '10:50'], ['11:00', '13:50'], ['14:00', '15:15'], ['15:30', '18:10']]
```